# CoreData Model Schema and Relationships

Tags: core-data, relationship

I have a question with relationships in my CoreData model.

I have two Entities for now. 1. Flight, 2 Airport
I have attached the screenshots of the model to this post.

The question I have is how do I related the flight to the airport. In my SQL Databased schema I have foreign keys for each but in CoreData how can I set up this relationship correctly.

Essentially the Flight has an Origin and a Destination.

[image: Schema in Editor Style]

[image]

[image]

[image: Flight]

[image: airports relationship]

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

AV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create two separate relationships between the two entities:

1. An “origin” relationship from Flight to Airport (to-one), with a to-many inverse relationship from Airport to Flight, “flightsStartingHere”, and
2. A “destination” relationship from Flight to Airport (also to-one), with a to-many inverse, “flightsTerminatingHere”.

Life gets more complicated if your flights have multiple stops.  In that case I would model each Flight as having several Legs, and each Leg an origin Airport and a destination Airport.  But the details will depend on the SQL database you are emulating.

Comment: Thanks pbasdf I think i have set it up ok. essentially on Flight it is all origin to destination for now for the MVP. Possibly with legs later but not likely. I have the two Entities with Airport having the relationship flightsStartHere (to many) with an inverse of origins and flightTerminatingHere (to many) with an inverse of destinations (to one). And flight having the relationship of origins (to one) and the inverse of flightsStartHere and also destinations with the inverse of flightTerminatingHere .  Is this the correct setup you mentioned.

Comment: @AVSoftware Yes, that's what I was suggesting.

Comment: Thanks I am new to CoreData and was trying to get my head around how Foreign Keys work